# why tomcat server not start properly in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

```
Mar 13, 2015 1:32:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin;.;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0/bin/../jre/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0/bin/../jre/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\nksharma\AppData\Roaming\npm;F:\software\eclipse;
Mar 13, 2015 1:32:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 13, 2015 1:32:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 13, 2015 1:32:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 331 ms
Mar 13, 2015 1:32:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 13, 2015 1:32:59 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
Mar 13, 2015 1:32:59 PM org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsSci onStartup
INFO: JSR 356 WebSocket (Java WebSocket 1.0) support is not available when running on Java 6. To suppress this message, run Tomcat on Java 7, remove the WebSocket JARs from $CATALINA_HOME/lib or add the WebSocket JARs to the tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip property in $CATALINA_BASE/conf/catalina.properties. Note that the deprecated Tomcat 7 WebSocket API will be available. 
Mar 13, 2015 1:32:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mar 13, 2015 1:32:59 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 13, 2015 1:32:59 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 267 ms
```

Hello 
I am trying to install the tomcat in eclipse. I am not able to install properly. When I check on browser it not started. I checked like that **http://localhost:8080/**, but `page not found` on browser. Could you please help me where i am doing wrong?

Comment: "INFO: Server startup in 267 ms"

Answer (score 0):

have you deployed tour application on tomcat?
have you tried to run tomcat independently to eclipse?: try startup.bat command (in bin directory of tomcat) and try to launch  http://localhost:8080/
what's happen?

Answer (score 0):

If you not getting any error in Tomcat log than your server is started properly without any error and application in that tomcat should run without any problem.

But from you question and log It may happen that your tomcat doesn't have root folder in you webapps directory or root application which is default application open when you type http://localhost:8080/

You may checked with deploying at least one application and open that application to check if problem still exist.